# I was writing Discord bot with index.js and .env and I messed with this error while running this in terminal "node index.js"

Tags: node.js

I want develop my own discord bot here's the contents:

**Index code**

```
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const { config } = require("dotenv");

// Declares our bot,
// the disableEveryone prevents the client to ping @everyone
const client = new Client({
    disableEveryone: true
});

config({
    path: __dirname + "/.env"
})

// When the bot's online, what's in these brackets will be executed
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Hi, ${client.user.username} is now online!`);

    // Set the user presence
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",
        game: {
            name: "me getting developed",
            type: "WATCHING"
        }
    }); 
})

// When a message comes in, what's in these brackets will be executed
client.on("message", async message => {
    console.log(`${message.author.username} said: ${message.content}`);
});

// Login the bot
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

**Output**

```
 disableEveryone = true
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Invalid shorthand property initializer` indicates that you used an invalid property initializer. In this case, it looks like you used "=" instead of ":" to declare the property value "true" on property "disableEveryone".

Saving the code as shared and running it again should solve your problem.